# Why does my function return an expression rather than a number?

Tags: output-formatting, number-representation, numerical-value

I feel like I'm going insane. I have a function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ which I need to evaluate using forward, backward and central first order finite differences with intervals `h=1.e-1, h=1.e-2, ...., h=1.e-14`.

```
f[x_] = (Exp[-(1 + x)^2] - Exp[-1^2])/x
```

But when I throw something in, say `f[1/10]` I get the following out:

```
10 (1/E^(121/100) - 1/E)
```

Basically, everything is in terms of `e`, and I need decimals. Can anyone help with this? I'm rather exhausted right now and I can't seem to figure out a solution, I am not very good with Mathematica.

Further, I have tried creating a list using

```
Table[1/(10^i), {i, 14}]
```

Which seems to give me the list which I can later map to the function, but of course also outputs in terms of e. Hopefully fixing one thing will fix the other.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, It seems to me that you just need to wrap your function definition inside the `N[...]` function, which will return the numerical value of its argument. You can also specify the number of digits of precision with the second argument to `N`.

Comment: As @MarcoB already has noted, you need to tell Mathematica that result of `f` is a number, otherwise Mathematica computes everything symbolically. So you can write : `f[x_]: = (Exp[-(1 + x)^2] - Exp[-1^2])/x//N;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica will perform an exact calculation if possible.  "E" means exactly *e*, rather than a numerical approximation i.e.  2.718 (with a few more decimal places).

When you calculate `f[1/10]` it gives the exact value because all of the inputs are exact.  If you want a numerical approximation, you can make any of the inputs approximate, or you can use `N` to get Mathematica to calculate a numerical approximation.  Any of the following methods will do:

(1)  pass an inexact value to `f`:

```
f[0.1]
(* -0.696822 *)
```

(2) put an approximate value in the definition of `f`

```
f[x_] = (Exp[-(1. + x)^2] - Exp[-1^2])/x
f[1/10]
(* -0.696822 *)
```

(3) put `N` in the function definition of `f`

```
f[x_] = N[(Exp[-(1 + x)^2] - Exp[-1^2])/x]
f[1/10]
(* -0.696822 *)
```

As some of the commenters pointed out, you probably want to use `:=` when you write functions.

Comment: Regarding `SetDelayed` I'd note, that an added bonus is a slight increase in speed when maintaining the symbolic `Exp` function. With `Set` `f[x_] = 2.71828^(-1.+x)^2...`, with `SetDelayed` it remains as `N[Exp[...]...` until evaluation. `First@AbsoluteTiming@Table[N[E^RandomReal[]], {1*^7}]` is about 30% faster than `First@AbsoluteTiming@Table[2.71828^RandomReal[], {1*^7}]`

Comment: Thank you so much! The explanation for exactly why it evaluates it in the way that it chooses was extremely helpful.